# TestNG : Go to the next test after one iteration of dataProvider

Tags: java, selenium, testng

So I have 2 Tests, one that check the sign up *`test01_signIn`*, if its a PASS, it goes to the the second test *`test02_CheckNewsStandElements`*, which checks the visibility of an element of the homepage, the only issue is that the first Test has a DataProvider like the following :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Data")
public void test01_signIn(String idMedia, String nomMedia, String idSSO, String mdpSSO, String lien) {
     //Test
}

@Test
public void test02_CheckNewsStandElements(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    WebElement modalCloseButton = null;
    modalCloseButton = nsp.modalCloseButton(driver);
    try{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(modalCloseButton));
    }catch(TimeoutException e){
        System.out.println("The Element isn't visible");
    }
}

@DataProvider(name="Data")
public Object [][] getLists() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Object [][] objects = newEDLI.importData().clone();
    return objects;
}
```

The results I get are more like :

```
Test1
Test1
Test1
...
Test2
Test2
Test2
```

While I'm looking for a result like this :

```
Test1 Test2 Test1 Test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject data into the test method using `@DataProvider` TestNg will run this method in a row as many times as many data you have. Also, there are no dependencies between your test methods. Hence, your `test01_signIn` executes independently from `test02_CheckNewsStandElements`.

You may consider using `@Factory` to organize the execution order. In this case, you inject data into the test class constructor (data provider should be static), and you are able to manage the order of your test methods execution:

```java
public class FactoryTest {
    private String idMedia;
    private String nomMedia;
    // .. rest of your data

    @Factory(dataProvider = "Data")
    public FactoryTest(String idMedia, String nomMedia, ...) {
        this.idMedia = idMedia;
        this.nomMedia = nomMedia;
        // set the rest of your fields
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "Data")
    public static Object[] getList() {
        return newEDLI.importData().clone();
    }

    @Test
    public void test01_signIn() {
        // use data from class members 
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test01_signIn")
    public void test02_CheckNewsStandElements() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
        WebElement modalCloseButton = null;
        modalCloseButton = nsp.modalCloseButton(driver);
        try{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(modalCloseButton));
        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            System.out.println("The Element isn't visible");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: although the tests will be executed in the correct order, in the test report they will still be grouped and sorted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after running the test, it shows an error :
No Tests were found.

Comment: @Xerox9000, how do you run your tests?

Comment: i have a testng.xml file that i run as a Suite test, which contains of course my class name

Comment: Then I suppose you need to check the data provider. I created a sample test class with `@Factory(dataProvider = "Data")` and this works fine for me. However, my test data is being declared in place with `new Object[] { ... }`